# Where can I find my custom SD card once added to the emulated device?

Tags: android-studio

I have added a custom SD card to an emulated device, but cannot find it anywhere in the device.

Steps taken:

1. ~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/mksdcard -l testsdcard 1G ~/testsdcard.img
2. Android Studio -> New Project -> Device Manager -> Create device -> Phone - Pixel XL -> Image - Tiramisu -> Show advanced settings -> SD Card -> External file -> ~/testsdcard.img -> Finish
3. Run device 'Pixel XL API 33'

Now I expect the SD card to be visible somewhere in the Files app or in the Settings -> Storage section but nothing to be found. There is only `/sdcard` which points to `/storage/emulated/0`, the default emulated card from Android Studio. Also when I run a custom app which gets all storage paths, nothing else shows up. Same for browsing through the Device File Explorer. What am I missing here / what goes wrong?

If it matters: I'm on a Mac M1, MacOS Venture with Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2

[image: View from within the Device File Explorer]